# Boost compilation is failing in boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp

Tags: c++, boost

I'm facing below compilation error from boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:

```
    In file included from ../../src/pamEmergencyBanner/pamEmergencyBanner.cpp:29:0:
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp: In constructor 'boost::move_upd::unique_ptr_data<P, D, false>::unique_ptr_data()':
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:133:9: error: expected identifier before 'do'
       : D(), m_p()
         ^
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:133:9: error: expected '{' before 'do'
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp: In constructor 'boost::move_upd::unique_ptr_data<P, D, false>::unique_ptr_data(P)':
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:137:9: error: expected identifier before 'do'
       : D(), m_p(p)
         ^
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:137:9: error: expected '{' before 'do'
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp: In constructor 'boost::move_upd::unique_ptr_data<P, D, false>::unique_ptr_data(P, boost::move_upd::unique_ptr_data<P, D, false>::deleter_arg_type1)':
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:141:9: error: expected identifier before 'do'
       : D(d1), m_p(p)
         ^
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:141:9: error: expected '{' before 'do'
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp: In constructor 'boost::move_upd::unique_ptr_data<P, D, false>::unique_ptr_data(P, const U&)':
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:146:9: error: expected identifier before 'do'
       : D(::boost::forward<U>(d)), m_p(p)
         ^
/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:146:9: error: expected '{' before 'do'
make[5]: *** [../../src/pamEmergencyBanner/pamEmergencyBanner.o] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/sunkrish/sunkrish_20160812104350_RUIM_AAA_CLog/SS_AAA/Pam/build/pamEmergencyBanner'
Errors building lib1 target
make[4]: *** [lib] Error 2
```

I tried checking any bug listed in [boost bugs](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/search?ticket=on) but didn't find much.

Boost version used:  1.60.0

Please let me know if there was bug created for this and corrected in later boost versions (tried checking, but didn't find any). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The error message suggests you have something like this:

```
#define D(A) do(A)
```

This is not a bug in boost, it's a bug in your program (which you haven't shown, so we can't really help you properly).

If it's not caused by a `#define` then it could be a command-line argument like `-DD(A)=do(A)`

Comment: Hi Jonathan Wakely,
Thanks for the reply.  Code is legacy and was working with Boost version 1.55.
After upgrading to 1.60.0 this compilation is failing.

Comment: That doesn't matter, it's still not a bug in Boost. Try adding `#define D 1` to your code and it should tell you where the bad macro is being defined.

Comment: Ok thanks, got the declaration of macro D.  That is in another library (PAM).

`/fpbuild/fpsdkroot_cougar/sysroots/x86_64/sysroot-FP-FPNSN5500-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/security/_pam_macros.h:190:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition`

Definition:
`#define  D(x)   do { } while (0)`

How to resolve this conflict, Should I #undef D in my code?  It will not be a clean solution Pls suggest.